# Create source directories in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

i'm a little bit confused about gradle projects creation.

How to create source sets directories in gradle?

is there a task for it?

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  Is the [Build Init plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: `mkdir src; mkdir src/main; mkdir src/main/java;`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Oli Charlesworth I was using an old version of Gradle (1.6) and there was no `gradle init` command, then I moved to the latest version and now works like a charm.